Is there a way to get data from a Dataflow entity without using Excel or Power BI's REST API?
I need to get data from a Dataflow entity but I can't figure out how to do that. Power BI's REST API doesn't work for me because I have a tight budget (i.e., no budget at all).
I have an Excel file that is connected to a Dataflow, and I also have a Python script that updates the data from the Excel file once a month. The file needs to be updated on a specific day. Unfortunately, things aren't going as expected, so I was wondering if there's a way to get data from a Dataflow without using Excel or Power BI's REST API.
Any ideas or solutions?
